# Reducing several lists of integers to one with no reoccuring numbers

Tags: c#, list, sorting, integer, reduce

I have several lists that have either none, one or a couple of integers in it.
What I like to achieve is to reduce each list to either zero [if the list was empty before] or only one integer off the list.
The tricky part starts here: Each remaining integer must be unique across all lists. Also I need to cut off the lists in a intelligent way so that as many lists with one entry as possible remain.

Examples:

```
List a contains: 5, 6, 14
List b contains: 3, 5
List c contains: 7
List d contains: 6
List e contains: [empty]

Best result would be:
List a: 5
List b: 3
List c: 7
List d: 6
List e: [empty]

Bad result what I like to avoid:
List a: 6
List b: 3
List c: 7
List d: [empty as the only possibility "6" was taken by list a already]
List e: [empty]
```

You see I sorted it in a way that List a did not take the 6 so List d has the chance to remain with the 6.

Is there any fancy algorithm, thinking of Linq or something, which would come in handy for such kind of problem?

Comment: Why not get all the unique elements first, then go list-wise to find which elements are in which list?

Comment: Yeah, something like that sounds smart. That would probably remain to be the easiest way of doing it.